# .htaccess 301 redirect friendly url

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

I'm trying to do a 301 redirect.

http://www.myweb.de/entdecke-panama/sternstunden-panamas to http://www.myweb.de/panama-urlaub/sternstunden/

mi code in .htaccess:

```
Redirect 301 /entdecke-panama/sternstunden-panamas http://www.myweb.de/panama-urlaub/sternstunden
```

but the result is: http://www.myweb.de/panama-urlaub/sternstunden-panamas
only does the redirection of the first "folder".

I'm doing something wrong?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you use two CMS at once like Joomla/Wordpress? Maybe you've to put the content "Redirect 301 /entdecke-panama/sternstunden-panamas http://www.myweb.de/panama-urlaub/sternstunden" at the beginning of the .htaccess file.